# JSP Tiles without Struts with Maven

Tags: java, jsp, maven, tomcat7, tiles

You can see in screenshots exception and the web.xml file to config tiles-defs.xml.

But i couldn't understand what is the problem about tiles? Is it wrong web.xml tiles configuration? Thanks for your attentions.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

tiles-defs.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
  <tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="homepage" template="/view/layouts/home.jsp">
   <put-attribute name="cssPaths" value="/view/tiles/common/cssPaths.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="metas" value="/view/tiles/common/metas.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="header" value="/view/tiles/common/header.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="footer" value="/view/tiles/common/footer.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="sliders" value="/view/tiles/common/sliders.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="featureditems" value="/view/tiles/common/featureditems.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="scripts" value="/view/tiles/common/scripts.jsp"/>
   <put-attribute name="brands" value="/view/tiles/common/brands.jsp"/>
  </definition>
 </tiles-definitions>
```

pom.xml

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
             <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
             <groupId>com</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
           <packaging>war</packaging>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <name>ecommerce Maven Webapp</name>
            <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
       <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>ecommerce</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Exception

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 14

11: <title>Urunler</title>
12: </head>
13: <body>
14:     <tiles:insertDefinition name="homepage"/>
15: </body>
16: </html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:124)
    org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:107)
    org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getCurrentContainer(TilesAccess.java:174)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertDefinitionModel.execute(InsertDefinitionModel.java:95)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertDefinitionTag.doTag(InsertDefinitionTag.java:254)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertDefinition_005f0(index_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

[image: exception]
[image]

Comment: No, I can't. Post text.

Comment: Also, they are in text. You can see

Comment: The stack trace is not in text: that's a picture.

Comment: edited again, stack trace is in text.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to [Configuring Tiles in your web application](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/configuration.html), it mentions as the following: -

#### 1 Required libraries

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artefactId>tiles-extras</artefactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

#### 2 Starting Tiles engine

Load the tiles container by using the appropriate listener it in your web.xml file.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.util.TilesDispatchServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Tiles Dispatch Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.tiles</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

AFAIU, we should configure the `listener` and/or `Tiles Dispatch Servlet` for starting Tiles engine. Please see further information at the following links: -

1. [Apache Tiles: Tutorial](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/index.html)
2. [Apache Tiles: Getting Start](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/getting_started.html)
3. [Apache Tiles: Configuration Reference](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/config-reference.html)

I hope this may help.

Comment: i have tiles-extras dependency, this listener and servlet are not useful for my app.